# Adding environment repository in Spring Config Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm fairly new to Spring Boot so please excuse me if I'm overlooking something simple.

With the Spring Config Server, you are able to specify via .yml files what type of environment repository that you would like to use (native, Git, etc).  These environment repositories are included in the third-party dependency.  I was wondering if it was possible to add your own environment repository so you can, for example, connect to a database to pick up configuration?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Were you able to hook up spring config server to a database? If so, would you mind sharing that solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you certainly can.  See [spring cloud consul config](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/tree/master/spring-cloud-consul-config) as an example.  The guts is a [PropertySource](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulPropertySource.java)

```
public class MyPropertySource extends EnumerablePropertySource<MyClient> {
  @Override
  public Object getProperty(String name) {
    return /* your impl */;
  }

  @Override
  public String[] getPropertyNames() {
    return /* your impl here */;
  }
}
```

You also need a [`PropertySourceLocator`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java), a [bootstrap configuration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration.java) and a [`META-INF/spring.factories`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories) that points to the bootstrap config`.

Comment: Ah, many thanks Spencer!  This looks like what I'm after.  I'll have a look into this.

Answer (score 2):

As spencergibb stated in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41552402/977985), a PropertySource only provides configuration for the config server itself and is **not** accessible for the spring boot config clients.

What you actually need is an implementation of the **EnvironmentRepository** interface.
I provided an example for a simple CustomEnvironmentRepository in [Spring Boot Config custom environment repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203585/977985)

Comment: I also created a small maven lib with a ZooKeeper EnvironmentRepository to be used as a plug and play dependency for Spring Cloud Config Server. See https://github.com/felixoldenburg/JonesEnvironmentRepository