# Spring cloud config server - how to add custom PropertySource visible in findOne() method of EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

**My goal** is to add custom PropertySource to spring-cloud-server. What I want to achieve is to get some custom properties from that custom source in spring-cloud-config-client application.

Basing on suggestions from [Adding environment repository in spring-config-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120491/adding-environment-repository-in-spring-config-server) I've created `spring-cloud-config-server` application and separate project `spring-cloud-config-custom`. Second one is based on [spring-cloud-consul-config](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/tree/master/spring-cloud-consul-config) code. So, I've created all necessary classes like `CustomPropertySource`, `CustomPropertySourceLocator`, `CustomConfigBootstrapConfiguration` and so on and configured them in `spring.factories`.

At the end, I've added maven dependency to `spring-cloud-config-custom` inside my `spring-cloud-config-server`.

So far so good. Everything works well. When I start server I can see that my `CustomPropertySource` is on the list of propertySources inside `EnviromentRepository` bean injected to `EnvironmentController`.

**Problem:** When I send GET request to `@RequestMapping("/{name}/{profiles}/{label:.*}")` (in `EnvironmentController`), injected `EnviromentRepository` bean is being used to find requested property source (`repository.findOne(name, profiles, label)` method). 
Unfortunately my property source could not be found here. Why?

I've spent a lot of time on debugging this. I've found that repository delegates `findOne()` method call to other repositories: `MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository` which delegates it to `NativeEnvironmentRepository`. Inside this delegates, findOne() method doesn't use propertySources from `EnviromentRepository` primary injected to controller. It creates new environment repository with new list of PropertySources and new separate SpringApplication. At the end, this list does not contain my `CustomPropertySource` and that is why `findOne()` returns empty propertySources in resulting `Environment` object.

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is `CustomPropertySourceLocator` (and/or `ConsulPropertySourceLocator`) supposed to be used (autowired/bootstrapped) in `spring-cloud-config-server` or `spring-cloud-config-client`
3. Can spring-cloud-config-server deliver many different kind of `PropertySources` at the same time, via REST interface (saying "different" I mean all Git, Consul and Zookeeper)?

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud are you using?  Up until very recently if there was another `EnvironmentRepository` bean in the context none of the default `EnvironmentRepository` beans would be created, so I am confused about how `MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository` or `NativeEnvironmentRepository` would be created in your case.  Can you perhaps provide a sample app that demonstrates the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I'm using 1.1.0.RELEASE.

Comment: I'm using 1.1.0.RELEASE. `EnvironmentRepository` injected to `EnvironmentController` is initially `EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository`. It delegates call to `MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository` which inherits implementation from `AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository`. FindOne() from the last one makes new `NativeEnvironmentRepository` passing `ConfigurableEnvironment` which contains my `CustomPropertySource` inside `bootstrapProperties` property source. It seams that  `NativeEnvironmentRepository` filters it because of  hardcoded "--spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=false" in getArgs() method.

Comment: Again some code that reproduces the problem would help.

Comment: I've prepared exemplary applications and make them available [here](https://github.com/mombip/spring-cloud-config-custom). Please compare results of calling of /myenv context on server and client side (http:/localhost:8888/myenv and http://localhost:8080/myenv). My custom property source ("custom") is not available on client side. Note that client doesn't use my CustomPropertySourceLocator directly. I'm trying to force server to serve CustomPropertySource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is adding a property source to the config server itself, not the configuration it serves. Adding `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to your config server and viewing `/env` reveals:

```
{
  "profiles": [

  ],
  "server.ports": {
    "local.server.port": 8888
  },
  "bootstrapProperties:custom": {
    "test.prop3": "CUSTOM-VALUE-3",
    "test.prop2": "CUSTOM-VALUE-2",
    "test.prop1": "CUSTOM-VALUE-1"
  },
}
```

To add something that will be served by config server, you have to implement an `EnvironmentRepository`.

Support for a composite `EnvironmentRepository` was [recently added](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/eb27590d8088a377fd1ce4aea7d0758be3593565).

Comment: Yes, that is what I finally did. I've implemented EnvironmentRepository and it works well. On the very beginning, I was convinced that `bootstrapProperties` defined on server side should be automatically accessible for configuration clients. Now I see, _I was wrong_. So conclusion is like this: Autoregistering `PropertySources` are for **internal use only** of application that registers it. In my case `config-server` can use my `CustomPropertySource` but not publish it. So, as I understand, there is no official way to make config-server to serve it's bootstrap `PropertySources`.