# Spring Cloud Config custom environment repository

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I am wondering is there an example how to create a custom EnvironmentRepository for Spring Cloud Config, cause there are git, svn, vault repositories, but I don't wanna use them, I need my custom one. For instance if I just want to store all properties in a Map.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Provide an implementation of the EnvironmentRepository as a bean in your application context. Spring cloud config server then will pick it up automatically.
Here's a minimalistic example:

```
public class CustomEnvironmentRepository implements 
EnvironmentRepository
{
    @Override
    public Environment findOne(String application, String profile, String label)
    {
        Environment environment = new Environment(application, profile);

        final Map<String, String> properties = loadYouProperties();
        environment.add(new PropertySource("mapPropertySource", properties));
        return environment;
    }
}
```

Note if you have multiple EnvironmentRepository (Git, Vault, Native...) you'd also want to implement the Ordered interface to specify an order.

A good approach is to look up existing EnvironmentRepository implementation like the [VaultEnvironmentRepository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/1b701ebdb6e999d40e6e0cdf8936ab792d00a503/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/VaultEnvironmentRepository.java) from the Spring cloud config server package.

Comment: I also created a small maven lib with a ZooKeeper EnvironmentRepository to be used as a plug and play dependency for Spring Cloud Config Server. See github.com/felixoldenburg/JonesEnvironmentRepository

Comment: I'm trying something similar here - but not working . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762915/custom-spring-config-environmentrepository-not-being-picked-up

Comment: I used a custom environment repository, but the config server no longer loads native nor git environment properties, only custom environment properties are loaded. I want load custom + native/git. Any ideas please

Comment: Ensure the profiles are active: SPRING_PROFILES-ACTIVE=git,keyvault