# Custom Spring config EnvironmentRepository not being picked up

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to figure out why my custom Environment Repository (in an embedded mode Spring Config application i.e. no stand-along Config server) isn't being picked up.

The object is obviously being constructed (I hit a log print statement at this point) but none of the properties I inject into it (from a hashmap for this example) show up in an env actuator dump i.e. custom.prop.* . The findOne(...) isn't being invoked.

Dump at 
https://gist.github.com/balamuru/1047db7080a4da6f067dd7cfac86a2c2

resulting from http://localhost:8282/env

Code at https://github.com/balamuru/config-service-embedded

Comment: with which profile are you starting your application?

Comment: The config in the "custom" profile isn't being picked up . ..... spring.profiles.active=git, custom, dev

Comment: Just tried your code. findOne is getting invoked.

Comment: Are you sure? The custom repository is constructed but the findOne isn't being invoked for me. See gist at https://gist.github.com/balamuru/6fc43e9dc8275a775e676dc3ea60b9b1 . I wonder if the environment is loaded too late in the llifecycle.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure. But you are right. it doesn't get called during the startup of the application. It is called after the application starts (after a few seconds )

Comment: Can you post a gist? I would expect to see the debug corresponding to ```log.info("\n###########\nTODO: connect to custom repository for " + application + ":" + profile + " at " + connectionString() + "\n###########\n");``` . I'll try again soon

Comment: It will only be invoked when queried

Comment: @spencergibb, If I uncomment the block of code starting with ```@Value("${custom.prop.1}")``` in EmbeddedConfigClientApplication.java , the property still doesn't resolve . Is that what you meant, .. or am I supposed to also create a PropertySourceLocator etc and somehow associate that with the custom EnvironmentRepostory? Thx